# Invalid ReDim in VBA function

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a function where I would like to create an array but it is not allowing me to ReDim the array inside the function.

```
Function engArray(rigStck As Variant) As Variant
    'CREATE ENGINE ARRAY WITH #, USAGE DAYS AND USED?
    If rigStck <> 0 Then
        ReDim engArray(1 To rigStck, 2)
        For n = 1 To UBound(engArray)
            'engine numbering
            engArray(n, 0) = n
            'reset engine usage to 0
            engArray(n, 1) = 0
            engArray(n, 2) = 0
        Next
    Else
        engArray(1, 0) = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Use a temp array `Dim TmpArray() as variant` then redim the temp array to the size you want.  Then at the end `engarray = TmpArray`

Comment: As Scott provided the solution, the reason is that your function is not an array itself that can be redim

Comment: Is `rigStck` originally a 2 column array? If it is not, you cannot `ReDim` it as such.

Comment: if re-dimensioning a multiple dimension array (i.e. a two dimensional one like you have), you can only change the size of the outer (second) dimension.

Answer (score 0):

To redim a multidemensional array, you need to get creative. You can only redim the outer dimension inherently so you will need to do something similar to this. If you need it to start at 1 instead of 0 you will want to tweak it a bit:

```
Public Function ReDimPreserve(aArrayToPreserve, nNewFirstUBound, nNewLastUBound) 'returns array with lbound starting at 0 and ending at designated amount
    ReDimPreserve = False
    'check if its in array first
    If IsArray(aArrayToPreserve) Then
        'create new array
        ReDim aPreservedArray(nNewFirstUBound, nNewLastUBound)
        'get old lBound/uBound
        nOldFirstUBound = UBound(aArrayToPreserve, 1)
        nOldLastUBound = UBound(aArrayToPreserve, 2)
        'loop through first
        For nFirst = LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 1) To nNewFirstUBound
            For nLast = LBound(aArrayToPreserve, 2) To nNewLastUBound
                'if its in range, then append to new array the same way
                If nOldFirstUBound >= nFirst And nOldLastUBound >= nLast Then
                    aPreservedArray(nFirst, nLast) = aArrayToPreserve(nFirst, nLast)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        'return the array redimmed
        If IsArray(aPreservedArray) Then ReDimPreserve = aPreservedArray
    End If
End Function
```